# Apache returns /index.php when accessing a missing file i.e. favicon.ico

Tags: apache

I have a website and I realized visiting an missing path, i.e. `https://example.com/favicon.ico` will actually return an identical http response as `https://example.com/index.php`

My goal is to return an empty string if favicon.ico does not exist rather than the contents of https://example.com/index.php

I have tried to create an empty file named `favicon.ico` in the file directory but this is not a permanent fix.

Comment: Revisit your rewrite rules, is it happening for any wrong pattern eg. https://example.com/abc?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the full url and check if it match index.php. When the last part of the url matches index.php you may send the default content. In all other cases it would be perfect to send a 404 HTTP-Status-Code and send your wished text.

Or you change your rewrite rules to a defined php script and send there a 404 site